# *ngFor and *ngIf on a <tr> element in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, ngfor, angular-ng-if

In my Angular 5 app I'm looping to create `tr` elements:

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
```

but I only want to show the row if certain conditions are met.  I know I can't use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` together, but I'm not seeing how to get around this.

I saw a post saying to add a template inside the tr with an `[ngIf]` construct but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax any longer.  If I try it like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
    <template [ngIf]="element.checked || showUnchecked">
```

then I get runtime errors.

> AppComponent.html:14 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]:
>       StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]:
>         NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getter that return the property elements already filtered. Something like

```
get filteredElements() {
    if( this.showUnchecked ) {
        return this.elements;
    } else {
        return this.elements.filter( () => { return this.checked; } );
    }
}
```

Comment: @gmazzotti I agree this solution works in this context. But can you explain why the error is coming in the first place

Comment: I never used the template directive so i cant help you. From my limited experience maybe you should use <ng-template> and not <template>.

Answer (score 1):

ng-container would work instead of template

```
<table><tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
<ng-container *ngIf="element.checked || showUnchecked">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</ng-container>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. In any case, this answer is far too brief to be useful.